# Finding blocks with Item Method in AutoCAD

Tags: python, pywin32, autocad

I am trying to automate some tasks in AutoCAD using Python and [`pywin32`](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/). AutoCAD version is 2018.

I have tried to follow the method shown here in the AutoCAD documentation: http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-A5B6ACC4-DCD8-4FE2-AB06-D3C3C349475B

I want to select a specific block, and then edit some of its attributes.

My code:

```py
acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
acad.ActiveDocument = acad.Documents.Open(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(baseDir,filename)))
time.sleep(2)
doc = acad.ActiveDocument   # Document object
entity = doc.Blocks.Item('TTLB ATTRIBUTES')
print entity.Name
print entity.HasAttributes
```

This correctly prints the block name, but attempting to access the `HasAttributes` property causes this error:

```
AttributeError: Item.HasAttributes
```

If I change the code to simply walk through all the objects, then it works:

```py
acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
acad.ActiveDocument = acad.Documents.Open(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(baseDir,filename)))
time.sleep(2)
doc = acad.ActiveDocument   # Document object
for entity in doc.PaperSpace:
    if entity.EntityName == 'AcDbBlockReference':
        if entity.Name == 'TTLB ATTRIBUTES':
            print entity.Name
            print entity.HasAttributes
```

I don't understand why the second one works and the first one doesn't. When I read the documentation, it seems like they should both be finding the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When invoking the [`Item`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-A5B6ACC4-DCD8-4FE2-AB06-D3C3C349475B) method on the [Blocks collection](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-E77CC5AD-74B8-472C-8270-32FD162D5653#GUID-E77CC5AD-74B8-472C-8270-32FD162D5653), you are obtaining a [**Block Definition**](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-E6F7B03B-F5CC-4A18-9C48-BBF1D32A31FD#GUID-E6F7B03B-F5CC-4A18-9C48-BBF1D32A31FD) object (`AcDbBlockTableRecord`), which is a container for the set of objects constituting the block geometry and does **not** have the [`HasAttributes`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-98EA1BF9-6259-45F0-87EF-CB97C012D0ED) property.

Whereas, when iterating over the objects held by the [Paperspace Collection](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-C5E998B5-6EB1-459A-98B1-444C74DB4516#GUID-C5E998B5-6EB1-459A-98B1-444C74DB4516) (which is itself a type of Block Definition), you are encountering [**Block Reference**](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-88EEBCA3-8AF5-4776-9D54-520B05AB9129#GUID-88EEBCA3-8AF5-4776-9D54-520B05AB9129) objects (`AcDbBlockReference`), which **do** have the [`HasAttributes`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-98EA1BF9-6259-45F0-87EF-CB97C012D0ED) property.

Consider that the Block Definition is essentially the "blueprint" for the block, and each Block Reference is an instance displaying the objects found within the block definition, at a specific position, scale, rotation & orientation in the drawing.

Attributes also have [Attribute **Definitions**](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-E24E7CA0-0120-4C55-BADB-46D701B8D4CB#GUID-E24E7CA0-0120-4C55-BADB-46D701B8D4CB) within the Block **Definition**, and corresponding [Attribute **References**](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-0630EFF2-51A2-46E4-A5A1-0377FB7E38E8#GUID-0630EFF2-51A2-46E4-A5A1-0377FB7E38E8) attached to each Block **Reference**. Such attribute references may then hold different text content for each block reference inserted in the drawing.

Aside, interestingly, attribute references may also be programmatically attached to a block reference independently of the block definition, however, this is not permitted when operating AutoCAD using the standard out-of-the-box front end.

With the above information, you will need to iterate over the block references found within the relevant layout container, and, if the block reference meets your criteria, iterate over the set of attribute references held by the block reference (which you can obtain using the [`GetAttributes`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-3E8E1756-F45D-4CCE-838B-00FBC0374278) method), changing the [`Textstring`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-E54B1951-5BF5-4524-97E6-DFB4E4A20109) property of those attributes which meet your criteria.